# How to store user multi-media content with node js and mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

I'm building a small social media website using nodejs and mongo db , how do I store the users multi-media content and display it , such as profile picture, videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mongodb's Gridfs ..

Q: What is Gridfs ?

Ans : GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the file into parts, or chunks [1], and stores each chunk as a separate document. By default, GridFS uses a chunk size of 255 kB; that is, GridFS divides a file into chunks of 255 kB with the exception of the last chunk. The last chunk is only as large as necessary. Similarly, files that are no larger than the chunk size only have a final chunk, using only as much space as needed plus some additional metadata.
*

Refer here for usage :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/